# How to change color of many pixels faster with python opencv?

Tags: python, image, opencv, pixel

I have a float image, the pixels values are -1 to 1 ( they're float) in a grayscale image.
I want to change pixel values in ranges. for example if 0.5<=pixel<=1, it will green.

I tried with this code but it no work because it never finishes or says a error that they are many pixels :(

If somebody knows how to change many pixels values faster, please comment!
Thanks!!

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import numpy

img = cv2.imread("C:\Python27\Archivos\Vinedo Casablanca\PythonOpencv\Seccion\ENDVI_seccion_hileras.tif", cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR | cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)
imgbgr = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
cvuint8=cv2.convertScaleAbs(imgbgr)
out = cv2.convertScaleAbs(imgbgr, alpha=(255.0/1.-1))


rows,cols,bands= out.shape
green = [0,255,0]
greenyellow = [4,255,173]
yellow = [0,255,255]
yellowred = [4,111,255]
red = [0,0,255]
for i in range(rows):
     for j in range(cols):
         for k in out[i,j]:

             if 153<=k<=255:
                    out.itemset((i,j,0),green[0])
                    out.itemset((i,j,1),green[1])
                    out.itemset((i,j,2),green[2])
             elif 51<=k<153:
                    out.itemset((i,j,0),greenyellow[0])
                    out.itemset((i,j,1),greenyellow[1])
                    out.itemset((i,j,2),greenyellow[2])
             elif 1<=k<51:
                    out.itemset((i,j,0),yellow[0])
                    out.itemset((i,j,1),yellow[1])
                    out.itemset((i,j,2),yellow[2])
```

Comment: Do not use loops for this operation. Instead work with masking.